# How to share VirtualBox guest OS images?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, lvm, pxe

I want to run multiple VirtualBox VM guests on the same Ubuntu (or Mac) host.

To save disk space, I'd like to have them all boot off of a single guest OS image (installed fully once on the first VM), with each of the remaining guests only having their own copies of /home, /etc, /tmp, /var/run, swap etc.

Is this possible via some combo of LVM, shared .vdi disks, PXE/network boot, NFS?

Comment: What happens when they all need to write different things to the drive?

Comment: @Tetsujin They will share the read-only OS image between them. In case of an upgrade, all get the same upgrade. Any differences to be instance-specific, example of which I listed above.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible with VirtualBox, but the technology you are describing does
exist and is called [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29),
produced by the [Docker company](https://www.docker.com/), and now available
on every major platform.

Docker containers can share code and disk, but any modifications are private
to the container that did them. Containers can also share data with the host
and with each other, and behave very similarly to virtual machines,
except that they are much more light-weight.

Comment: My issue with Docker is:  1. It's an app-container, and not a system/platform container. I need a full-fledged OS with cron-jobs, start-up services running and many of them. Docker afaik discourages use of multiple apps/services per container. Need to simulate production env as much as possible.  2. I need to often test things on RHEL 6.5, docker containers for which I don't think are available.  3. Would've loved to use LxD (to somewhat achieve my original of saving disk space), but it's not availabe on Mac.

Comment: Note: I'm quite surprised to learn that even with sophisticated OSes like Linux and Mac (BSD-based) what I asked for originally isn't possible. Sad.

Comment: AFAIK, it's possible to [Run multiple services in a container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) and also [run a cronjob inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container). The problem with multiple processes is said to be mostly monitoring for failed containers. Converting monolithic architecture into multiple docker containers is certainly not an easy job.

Comment: Note: I never tried, but if you isolated in VirtualBox enough data in a read-only volume, it might be possible to mark the file as read-only and share it among VMs.